# What are some features I should seek in a rugged swimming tracker?

Tags: swimming, tracking, motivation

A dedicated activity tracker for a bicycle, a [cyclocomputer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/68520/48599), does wonders to one's training. Suddenly every kilometer "counts". Every speed increment matters.

I would now like to do the same for swimming, with the main objective of tracking to push myself to swim longer and faster.

I am not asking for product recommendations. What's sold in your market may anyway not be available in mine.

What are some features I should seek in a rugged swimming tracker? My cyclocomputer and heart rate monitors would do the trick nicely, but neither is remotely waterproof.

Related:

- [Tracking open water breaststroke swimming distance](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/40714/36896)